# can't boot GP Peak after update

Tags: firefox-os

I've updated from 1.4 to 1.4 (cause I wasn't able to connect to the Wi-fi, I must do it this way). It was official version from GP. Everything was correct, but after update I can't boot it, there is just screen with logo. I can't connect it to the adb (so adb shell dmesg is not posible).
I tried to remove data, recovery and reboot bootloader from fastboot, but nothing help. How could I load there again version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to try on these devices is restart with phone plugged in, while running on your computer:

```
adb wait-for-device reboot bootloader
```

As sometimes ADB sees the device for a little while. If that doesn't help:

1. First remove the battery of the phone and unplug it from your computer
2. Put the battery back in and hold POWER, VOLUME UP & VOLUME DOWN buttons (**hold them all, otherwise you'll end up in recovery**)
3. You'll end up in the bootloader
4. Plug in the device, and you can see it again in fastboot

When you're in the bootloader, go to the folder where you downloaded the 1.4 image and run the flash command.

A hanging loading screen is most of the times caused by not clearing userdata. For next time, backup data first via [this script](https://github.com/Mozilla-TWQA/B2G-flash-tool/blob/master/backup_restore_profile.sh), flash, if it doesn't boot without clearing userdata, clear it. Then restore with the same script.

Comment: Thank you, finally I must reboot bootloader manualy from phone and than run:

`./fastboot flash boot boot.img`

`./fastboot flash system system.img`

`./fastboot flash recovery recovery.img`

`./fastboot erase cache`

`./fastboot reboot`